# Ant Design Notification not using custom styling in React App

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am currently having an issue trying to use custom styling for Ant Design's Notification module. Here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import "./notification.less";
import { Button, notification } from "antd";

const openNotification = () => {
  notification.open({
    message: "Notification Title",
    description:
      "This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification. This is the 
content of the notification.",
    className: "notification-type-info"
  });
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Button type="primary" onClick={openNotification}>
    Open the notification box
  </Button>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Here is what's in my notification.less file

```
.notification-type-info {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #1890ff;
}
```

Here is where i'm testing the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-style-ant-design-demo-n0yh7

Anything particular i'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to modify the parent ant container using ::global and only have the css class be invoked within the required component.